# Extract class information

Tags: c#, roslyn, documentation-generation, nrefactory

I need to create some kind of documentation for my code. For this I have to extract information from few hundreds of C# classes.

Basically each class contains some method `MyMethod`. In this method there is maybe a `switch` case with few cases. Overall code structure is like this

```
MyMethod()
{
..some code..

switch (variable)
    case "A":
          break;
    case "B":
          break;

..some other code..
}
```

All I need is lookup for a switch case in `MyMethod` and extract `case` values.

So far I came up with option to use Roslyn or Nrefactory to parse all .cs files and then using ASTs look into them to extract AST nodes I need.

But this approach looks a bit odd, since the task can PROBABLY be perfectly automated in some other way. I have clear files structure, I know exactly method name I need to check, and there is exactly one `switch` statement inside of it. Always.

Are there any other convenient ways to extract information and generate this documentation ?

Comment: Roslyn is your friend. This seems perfect for a SyntaxWalker: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/07/26/learn-roslyn-now-part-4-csharpsyntaxwalker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only things that I can think of is to either parse the C# files or parse the compiled IL using Mono.Cecil or similar. In the former case, my friend has written a C# parser [available here.](https://github.com/Timwi/ParseCs)

Of course if you are going the parse-cs way, Roslyn is now a suitable option as you mentioned. there is a quick introduction here: http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse C# code. Using anything other than a proper C# parser (like Roslyn or NRefactory) will lead to very brittle code.

For example, you'll start by searching for the string `void MyMethod()`. Then you'll find that one type has `void MyMethod( )` instead, so you change the search to the regex `void\s+MyMethod\s*\(\s*\)`. Then some file will contain `void MyMethod()` in a comment or a string, so you'll write code that (imperfectly) detects comments and strings.

After a while, you reach a point where you've gradually built a very primitive C# parser and you're dreading what kind of code will it need to support next.

If you start with a proper C# parser, you won't have these kinds of problems. So, unless the performance of that is totally unacceptable for you, I think you should use it.